# How should I use UIMA Ruta to match the all words between line break?

Tags: uima, ruta

Thank for any strong hands!

I have some text like the following

```
aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa
bbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbbbbb
cccccc ccccc ccccc cccccc
```

I want to use Ruta to create annotation that matches all strings between line break. I want my annotation to create the following three match:

```
1. aaaaa aaaa aaaaa aaaaaa
2. bbbbb bbbbb bbbb bbbbbb
3. cccccc ccccc ccccc cccccc
```

I try to match everything between line break, like the following

```
BREAK #{-> MARK(Stuff)} BREAK;
```

But no luck. Could anyone please make some suggestion?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Beware of different line endings if the source of the document is unknown. It is sometimes necessary to take a closer look at the line breaks ("\n", "\r") in order to distinguish new lines from free lines.  The BREAK annotations are created for both types, and if two chars are used for a line break, then there are also two BREAK annotations. The analysis engine mentioned in my answer should take care of that problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your rule is probably the currently used filtering setting. Whitespaces, breaks and markup are not visible by default. The rule is probably not able to find any anchors to start the match process. You need to make breaks visible for the rules, e.g, with RETAINTYPE:

```
Document{-> RETAINTYPE(BREAK)};
BREAK #{-> MARK(Stuff)} BREAK;
Document{-> RETAINTYPE}; // for restoring the default setting
```

There is also an analysis engine that is able to create these annotations:
[PlainTextAnnotator](http://uima.apache.org/d/ruta-current/tools.ruta.book.html#ugr.tools.ruta.ae.plaintext).
This analysis engine includes however also whitespaces at the beginning and end of the line. These could be removed with something like:

```
Document{-> RETAINTYPE(SPACE)};
Line{->TRIM(SPACE)};
```

In UIMA Ruta 2.2.1 (next release) you can also write something like:

```
Document{-> RETAINTYPE(BREAK)};
(#{-> Stuff} BREAK)+;
```

*(I am a developer of UIMA Ruta)*

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. Your answer does give me hope. Thank you. I have found Ruta intuitive. But I really have difficulty in learning this. When I read the Ruta rule, everything make sense. But when I try writing my own rules, I ve found it very difficult. Maybe it is because Ruta is too intuitive and not as vigorous as other languages, like Java.

Comment: I know what you mean. Especially the concept of coverage-based visibility brings many advantages, but causes also often cluelessness about what went wrong. Feel free to ask any question. I will gladly answer all as soon as it is possible. You can also ask your questions at the mailing list user@uima.apache.org - Normally, it takes less time to get an answer there since I often check my mails, but not always this site.